# Pycharm cant install packages

Tags: python, pycharm, package

I'm having an issue installing any package using PyCharm. It has a problem with my name "João" because of the character 'ã'.

```
C:\\Users\\Jo\xe3o\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\\...
```

Error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe3' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What can I change to fixed?

Comment: That's not a Pycharm issue. It's inherent to Python 2 and pip.

Comment: @BobDylan and what i can do to solve it? Without using Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [documented problem](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2501) in pip.

Here's a pretty straight-forward solution posted by one user on the issue thread:

Python 2 implicitly tries to decode bytes from p_path to unicode as ascii and because thats not possible, you should add decoding as latin1 in LockBase's __init__.py (in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg\pip_vendor\lockfile\__init__.py`):

```
self.hostname = socket.gethostname()
```

should be changed to this:

```
self.hostname = socket.gethostname().decode('latin1')
```

And in case that didn't work, here is the more excruciating solution posted by the issue OP, but it's a **massive** pain:

- Change your name (with no loss of data) to a fully ascii version by following these instructions http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/147545-user-profile-folder-change-user-account-folder-name.html
- Remove all versions of Python
- Reinstall Python 3.4 ( Which includes pip - you could presumably also reinstall 2.7 and install pip separately but I didn't )
- Remove all references to Python27 in user variable PATH and system variable Path. ( Start->right click Computer->Properties->Advanced system settings->Environment Variables)
- Ensure these both contain C:\Python34 and C:\Python34\Scripts
  Add a few restarts to taste
  Pro-tip: Avoid giving your children names with non-ascii characters

Comment: The first option didn't work, guess i will try the second and long version :)